# Parallel programming with threads on specific static method in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have this code:

```
public final class AClass{   
    static Long x=0;
    public static Long aMethod(args...){

        //commands
        x = aMethod(args...);
        x += aMethod(args...);
        //commands
    }

}
```

I want to execute the two lines of code(the two calls of `aMethod`) parallel with threads.

Comment: What's stopping you?

Comment: Hi Justas,  threads  take as a parameter object and no methods..

Comment: I suggest you start reading this from the start: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: Oh please, this is a "Abstract" code , 
I hoped to understand the essence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a relatively simple problem and the following code should solve your predicament

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
   public void run() {
      x = aMethod(args...);
   }
};

Thread thread2 = new Thread() {
   public void run() {
     x += aMethod(args...);
   }
};

thread1.start();
thread2.start();
```

Then you join the result with:

```
thread1.join();
thread2.join();
```

These 2 lines of code will throw an InterruptedException and will need to be handled with a try/catch

Comment: That approach is not thread safe. If both threads modify the variable at the same time you could get undefined behavior. You can fix it by making x an `AtomicLong`. Alternatively you could also work with `CompletableFuture`.

Comment: Or you could use parallel streams. That would by far be the shortest way to write it.

Comment: Not a good solution. If thread2 finishes before thread1 then thread1 will overwrite the value in x.

Comment: If i make method synchronized?